# How to open two activities in single button click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-spinner, android-button

I have two radio buttons where it calls same spinner arrays. So based on radio buttons how to call two activities. My code are as follows:
 in this i use two radio buttons,spinner and a button in xml

A.java

```
     Spinner selectcity;
 RadioGroup rg = null;
 RadioButton rb1,rb2;
 Button searchbutton;
     rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
 rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.seekers);
 rb2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.posting);  
 selectcity = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.statespinners);
     rb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  
     {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
selectcity=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.statespinners);
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
SearchCity.this, R.array.cities, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);   
  selectcity.setAdapter(adapter);   
  }
  });
  rb2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  
  {
  @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
selectcity=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.statespinners);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 =  ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
SearchCity.this, R.array.area, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);    
selectcity.setAdapter(adapter1);
}        
});
searchbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.statebutton);
searchbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {                    


  //here i am strucked how to call two activities based on radio buttons selection
    }
    });
```

How use two radio button change and to call two different activities.
 (A and B).Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want, you mean if one radio buttion is selected you have to goto activity A otherwise activity B???

Comment: You asked "How to open two activities". I think you mean "How to open one of the two activities". isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are struggled with this. You could have a reference to the radio group and use `getCheckedRadioButtonId ()` to get the checked radio button id.

```
int id = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
if (id == -1){
//no item selected
}
else{
if (id == R.id.seekers){
    //call activity A
}
if (id == R.id.posting){
    //call activity B
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Do like this.

searchbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.statebutton);
searchbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if(rb1.isChecked()){ //radio button rb1
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent intent=new Intent(this,ActivityA.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
else
{
if(rb2.isChecked())//radio button rb2
{
Intent intent=new Intent(this,ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
}
}

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId){            
if(checkedId == R.id.seekers)
{
// Call First Activity
}else if(checkedId == R.id.posting)
{
// Call Second Activity
}
}
```